# How to reduce Ethereum DAG size in private network?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using Go Ethereum and I am trying to use it for a private network, but the blockchain DAG takes up a lot of disk space on a light weight system. What things can be done to make it more light weight?

Comment: Can you define lightweight? Do you mean Ethereum has too many features right now? It takes up too much RAM? Takes up too much disk space? Too slow? What is the target system? Do you mean light as in an 8-bit embedded processor, Raspberry Pi Zero, iPhone, 10-year-old-desktop computer, a netbook, a laptop, living in a small VPS, or something else?

Comment: in terms of how can i reduce the size of DAG file or how to stop the generation of DAG file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using proof of work, you can use [proof of authority](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Proof-of-Authority-Chains) in Parity, if that is applicable to your situation. If not, you can change the size of the DAG in the `geth` source file `./consensus/ethash/algorithm.go`. The values for `datasetInitBytes` and `datasetGrowthBytes` are probably of interest to you. You will also need to update the table named `datasetSizes` and the table in the file `vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/src/libethash/data_sizes.h`. You can delete the DAG files when they are "stale" using something like a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will need to have at least one node (preferably more) in full sync to as `an archive` with validated transactions and state. It may run on the strongest device in your network. The rest may run in a `lightSync` mode fetching necessary data from the archive on request.